# Find highest earning company from while loop

Tags: loops, while-loop, max, highest

I need to find the company with the highest earnings.

So far I am able to pull out the highest total Earnings from the loop but have no idea how to get the company name that ties with this highest earnings.

while( count <= noOfComp)

```
{   
    System.out.print("Enter Company: ");
    companyName = kb.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Number of hires: ");
    noOfHires = kb.nextInt();
    kb.nextLine();


    //calculations
    totalEarnings = noOfHires * 2500 + 10000;
    System.out.println("Total Earnings of company is :" + totalEarnings);
    totalEarned = "" + totalEarnings;



    if(totalEarnings > large )                          //If statement for largest number
    {
     large = totalEarnings;
    }


    allTotalEarnings += totalEarnings;
    count++;


}
```

Comment: Just curious: are you adding a string with an integer? `totalEarned = "" + totalEarnings;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign the highest earning company name and its earnings in variables after the calculation by comparing with previous highest with calculated one.

```
String highCompanyName = "";int highCompanyEarning = 0;
while( count <= noOfComp)
{   
    System.out.print("Enter Company: ");
    companyName = kb.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Number of hires: ");
    noOfHires = kb.nextInt();
    kb.nextLine();


    //calculations
    totalEarnings = noOfHires * 2500 + 10000;
    System.out.println("Total Earnings of company is :" + totalEarnings);
    totalEarned = "" + totalEarnings;


    if(totalEarnings> highCompanyEarning )  //If statement for largest number
    {
        highCompanyEarning = totalEarnings;
        highCompanyName = companyName;
    }


    allTotalEarnings += totalEarnings;//the purpose of it is not clear so left as it is.
    count++;
 }
 System.out.println("Highest Earnings company is :" + highCompanyName );
 System.out.println("Earning of that company is :" + highCompanyEarning );
```